# How to check if managed item purchased or not in inapp purchase V3 android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app

I got stuck in a section for few days. The issue is that,

I implemented `Inapp purchase(V3)` in my project. the purchase item is a button called `ads_removal`. I can able to purchase it and paid it already. I added `ads_removal` as managed product in Inapp products in play store, but after I purchase the item, ads still showing in the application. I don't know how to check if the product purchased and hide ads in the application. I think about checking it in the splash screen itself. But got confused how to do it.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Hi Shanu786, Did you get a solution for this?

Comment: Hi Noundla... yes i got the solution few days ago. but its not in a standard way i think. i didnt use restore button. Instead of that, i check the app is purchased or not in the splashscreen by  calling startSetup() and inside this called queryInventoryAsync method and check it and saved a value in shared preference and checked in the whole app. Do u have any other suggestions? Thanks for asking anyways :) :)

Comment: I'm also verifying for the same usecase. However, didn't find proper way without having server communication. But my app won't connect to any server. So i am also thinking the same way as you did. However, I am storing the value in bool variable runtime, instead of SP. So will check every launch of the app. This way it can be saved a little bit.

Comment: i check what i did in all cases, means, after sucessfull purchase and uninstalled the app, it still works fine, thats y i asked :) :)